# Highcharts - HeatMap - How to show data label only for a maximum number of points?

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I have a large heatmap. I am using boost.js.

Everything works properly, but...when I insert data labels, browser freezes.

One possible way to deal with this, is to show data labels only after zoom. If the selected area contains a maximum of 100 points, then insert data labels.

I struggled to build this condition, but I failed.

Here is the fiddle: [Fiddle Large Heatmap](https://jsfiddle.net/joaosalles/g0f9atjw/5/)

When `numOfPeriods` is large enough (>10 e.g.), browser freezes. But, if `numOfPeriods` is large and the `plotOptions` session and `dataLabels` settings are commented, everything works fine.

Then, I kindly ask any help to show point labels when the selected area after zooming contains 100 point or less.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @O Pardal, First of all, your chart is not boosted - `boostThreshold: 0` means that it is diabled. It is boosted here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L423ho7d/ but it doesn't play well with data labels and has some limitations related with chart height. For toggling data labels you could use `selection` event, but also - zooming doesn't seem to work with such amont of points. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h0yvzsag/

Comment: Thank you @ppotaczek, sorry for the late reply. Do you know , at your last fiddle, how to enable data labels on selection zoom event and disable when resesting zoom? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @O Pardal, Use `selection` event and update data labels properties: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tuL80rgb/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @ppotaczek! As you said, data labels does not work properly in boost mode with such amount of points. I tried to set datalabels only in zoom mode (with a reduced number of points). But I think that datalabels is being assessed for each point and crashing the browser. Is there a way to loop over only selected point in zoom? My idea is to set data label only for the selected points.

Comment: Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hko1vqLs/ I filter out unvisible points.